# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter - When Select ALL, returns zero rows

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

My current definitions for this report are like this:

DataSet A = a pretty extensive query with 'AND ai.Channel IN (@ChannelParameter)'

DataSet B = Channel 'Select distinct channel from Account_Info'
result set 'Retail Channel' or 'Wholesale'

Parameter = @ChannelParameter is set to Allow Multiple Values and is Getting the values from Query.

Tablix Properties - Filters
Expression [Channel]
Operator IN
Value  =Parameters!ChannelParameter.Value(0)

When I run the report and select 'Retail Channel', I get the correct data.
When I run the report and select 'Wholesale', I get the correct data.
When I run the report and select both values, I get zero rows returned.

When I modify the query for DataSet A to be ai.Channel IN ('Retail Channel','Wholesale'), I get all of the rows. There are no rows in the data where the Channel field is NULL.

I've seen and tried some changes to the expression in the parameter using a JOIN statement, but no better results there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter expression is incorrect, as you stated `(0)` that means only the first parameter value will be used.

Having said that, it looks like you are already filtering the data in your `A` dataset so there is no need for the tablix filter, just remove it.

Comment: Thank you, Alan.    I had tried the (0) and the not (0).  I had tried .Value .IsMulti, etc.  I had tried without the  AND statement in my SQL Dataset.    In the end, it looks like the Tablix Properties WITH the other values was causing the bad behavior.